# Facebook API returning wrong unread thread count

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to query the [thread](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/thread/) FQL table to get all unread messages, and also the count of unread items in the thread.

This is how I query the table:

```
SELECT thread_id,updated_time,snippet,snippet_author,unread FROM thread WHERE folder_id=0 AND unread!=0
```

From reading the doc to which I linked above, it seems to me that `unread` should include the count of unread messages in the thread.

However, I just tested the above call and Facebook gives me back a value of `unread=1`, despite the thread in question having 4 unread items.

This is how the thread looks on `facebook.com` (notice the `(4)`, showing that `unread` should be `4`):

[image]

This is what the API returns to me, which is wrong (notice the `"unread":1`):

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "name":"messages",
      "fql_result_set":[
        {
          "thread_id":"BLAH BLAH BLAH",
          "updated_time":1333317140,
          "snippet":"BLAH BLAH BLAH",
          "snippet_author":BLAH,
          "unread":1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: `count of unread items` by this `unread!=0` ?

Comment: @HamzaWaqas: it's standard FQL for getting only threads having some unread items...

Comment: @HamzaWaqas: Facebook doc says that `unread` is the `The number of unread messages in the thread`, which is not what I'm seeing.

Comment: Try first by getting all the threads. See, is it coming fine or not..

Comment: I think see timestamp `22 minutes ago`. It returns total unread number of threads, not unread number of messages.

Comment: @HamzaWaqas: no, that's simply false, please read the docs. I checked this again now by marking 3 threads as unread. For each of them, `unread=1`.

Comment: @HamzaWaqas: and the `unread!=0` in the FQL query is just fine, trust me. I appreciate your willingness to help, but some basic SQL/FQL knowledge will probably be required :)

Comment: See, I worked with FBAPI a long ago. But, As what I got, it is returning unread threads. Not unread messages. See, If I sent you 3chat messages or inmail, and you didn't replies so they are in unread. However, just sent by me that's why I was only 1 there. So, it is treating threads. Not messages. I think this is the issue man!

Comment: @HamzaWaqas: again, PLEASE READ THE DOCS. Yes, it is returning threads. But for each thread, it is also supposed to return a count of the unread messages IN THAT THREAD.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the `thread` table does not exactly correspond to reality anymore.

Using the `unified_thread` table instead fixes the issue. However, the Facebook doc says that production apps should use `thread` at the current time...